# how to add a new class on load function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want that if the file extension is .jpg then assign a new class to button and hide the textbox. on flie load function this is my code what am i doing wrong ?

HTml

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select image to upload:
   <input type="file" class="flUpload" name="image" id="fileToUpload image">
   <input type="text" class='result' id='result'/>
   <input type="submit" class="btnClick" id='btn' value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $target_dir = "uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
   echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

jQuery

```
 <script>
 $(function () {
  $('#image').load(function () {
    if ($('.flUpload').val() != '') {
      var file = $('.flUpload')[0].files[0];
      var fileName = file.name;
      var fileExt = '.' + fileName.split('.').pop();
      if(fileExt == ".jpg"){
        alert(fileExt);
        $(".result").hide();
        $(".btnClick").addClass('newclass');
      }
    }
    else {
     alert('Please select a file.')
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are entering wrong `id` of file picker and you need to change event name to `change`

```
$(function () {
  $('input[name="image"]').change(function () {
        //............
  });
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr5trvs3/)

It will help you.